# How to use cmd to save string and the output of findstr together?

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd, findstr

(Platform: Win7)
I am able to directly save the output of what "findstr" command find.

```
findstr /S /N "#ifdef" *.cpp >D:\Test\123.txt
```

and the output looks like this:

> dealloc.cpp:3:#ifdef 1

But I just can't to make it save in the format like

> file name:dealloc.cpp line:3

how do I add the string "file name:"before the file found by findstr command and add string "line" before that number? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Install a proper tool like `grep` or `awk`.

Answer (score 4):

If this is what you want you can add redirection on the second line:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /S /N "#ifdef" *.cpp') do (
   (echo(file name:%%a line:%%b)
)
```

Comment: This will have to be adjusted if the specified search path includes the drive letter because of the extra `:`